# .NET console app sometimes succeeds to run second - blocked - console app, but not always. Why?

Tags: .net-core, windows-10, ntfs, windows-11

I'm creating **two** .NET 6 console applications. Let's call them `A.exe` and `B.exe`. They are not signed.

`A.exe` is run by the user. At some point, `A.exe` launches `B.exe` using `Process.Start(...)`.

This works well.

Both applications are distributed as portable apps in a zip file that can be downloaded from the internet. After downloading and unzipping, the user has to **unblock** `A.exe` to run it, otherwise a big blue window pops up, saying that running the file is not allowed (because unsigned). At least on Windows 10 and Windows 11. (Under the hood, Windows is flagging the downloaded files via NTFS Alternate Data Streams.)

Unblocking is done by the user by right-clicking `A.exe`, selecting `Properties`, then checking `Unblock`:

[image]

On some machines the unblocked `A.exe` can run `B.exe`, even if `B.exe` is technically still blocked. `A.exe` starting `B.exe` even **unblocks** the app, so the Unblock option disappears from the Properties dialog of `B.exe`.

**But not on all machines.** In some environments `A.exe` fails to start `B.exe` and the user first has to manually unblock `B.exe`. No auto-unblock there.

Why is that? Under which circumstances is automatic unblocking happening, and when does it have to be done manually by the user?

Comment: It was an old trick, back in the XP days, to unblock files by zipping them.  Worked because unzippers did not know anything about NTFS streams.  No real idea if they do now, but clearly it will depend on what unzipper the user used and what kind of security software they have.  Ask about it at superuser.com

Comment: @HansPassant This is unrelated to the unzipper in my view. On my machine the unzipped files get properly flagged as blocked (looking into the ADS of the extracted exe files shows the zip as origin). So Win 10 up have their act together since A and B are both blocked. But unblocking A is enough for B to be run as well, on my machine. But not on all machines - and so far I cannot reproduce that. Just get the occasional ticket. Nevertheless... still better to ask on SuperUser? Was not sure since it's programming adjacent.